# How to resolve notification issue in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing notification related things.Problem is `click on button`.  I wrote the following notification related code  :

```
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            "New update received", when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            MessageReceivedActivity.class);     

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);  
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("post_title", message);
    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);   

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Agility Logistics", "New update received", intent);
    //      notification.number +=1;
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

If button is clicked, the button `onclick notification` is overriding all the other notifications.This is undesirable. So how can I show all notifications received without having them overwritten by button click notification ?

Comment: Can you clean up the question? Some code is appearing as normal text which makes it difficult to read. In addition, it is not clear what specific issue you are trying to solve. What currently happens? What do you want to happen?

Comment: sorry i am edit the code. problem notification is override.

Comment: Don't bother, i have already edited your code. But your code sample is incomplete. Where is the button click call ? How are you loading the notification(s) on click of the button. Add those codes there.

Comment: first click notification is came next click another notification came but override previous one .how to take queue manner.

Comment: So what you mean is , on 2nd click , you want to capture the `1st notification + 2nd notification`and  on 3rd click , you want to capture the `1st notification + 2nd notification + 3rd notification` and so on and so forth, is that so ?

Comment: No i am asking in  notification bar only showing one notification.

Comment: Normally for collapsing notifications it is set as :

`PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and to push them off the queue its used as `PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));` So if you want all the notifications queued, then don't use either of those 2 flags.

Comment: PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); this is correct or not